# Progressive matrix with squares which have colored petals and dots

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

[image: Last Item Matrigma IQ test]

Found this at Reddit ([r/cognitive testing](https://www.reddit.com/r/cognitiveTesting/comments/vmo1hr/the_last_item_on_the_matrigma_iq_test/)) apparently it’s from a free IQ test called Matrigma. What do you think the correct answer is?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is option

> A

Reason

> In each step you rotate the object 90° clock-wise. **1.** If there is no dot inside, then in the next object you add a white "semi" circle to the side of the square and you also add a dot inside. **2.** If there *is* a dot inside, then in the next object you remove a black "semi" circle from the side of the square and you also remove the dot inside. The "semi" circles added/removed are always on opposite edges.

To illustrate:

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]